# Why are tidal forces conformally invariant?

Tags: general-relativity, curvature, conformal-field-theory, tidal-effect

Tidal forces are encoded in the Weyl-tensor $C^\mu_{\nu\lambda\sigma}$. It is well-known that the Weyl-tensor is invariant under conformal transformations: $g'_{\mu\nu}(x) = \Omega(x)g_{\mu\nu}(x)$.
In other words tidal forces are conformally invariant. Can this be understood intuitively ?

Comment: I do not think that actual tidal forces on macroscopic bodies are conformally invariant. They depend on more than just the local curvature (or to stay in a more accessible Newtonian framework, the derivative of the gravitational potential). I believe it makes intuitive sense that the first order approximation of tidal forces is conformally invariant. Maybe I am overlooking something?